# iPhone static library linking error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using a bunch of custom static libraries to build a test app.  However, I keep getting the following linker error: `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_<MainClassOfMiddleLevelLibrary>", referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-MainClassOfMiddleLevelLibrary in lib<HighLevelLibrary>.a(<HighLevelLibrary>.o)`  However, when I build the (HighLevelLibrary) project, it links and builds just fine.  I have already set up the Header Search Paths and included the libraries in my Frameworks group.  Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Weird.  Works fine when linking (LowLevelLibrary1) and (LowLevelLibrary2), both of which (MiddleLevelLibrary) depends upon, but the moment I add (MiddleLevelLibrary) it claims that it cannot find the main class of (MiddleLevelLibrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are building a static library, you are just creating an archive of *.o files. There are no linking stage. If you are using in your static library anything that is declared but not implemented, the library will be built without any error.
Actual linking occurs when you are building an application. So all the lining dependencies (MiddleLevelLibrary in your case) should be added to your application (and not to HighLevelLibrary).

Comment: Hmm, the (MiddleLevelLibrary) IS linked into my application (or was anyway).  I want to build this so that I ONLY have to link to (HighLevelLibrary) to gain all of the functionality and classes of the libraries below it.  I suspect this is how things like UIKit and other "wrapper" libraries work: they have sub-libraries that are embedded and linked already so that the higher level library exposes the lower level elements.  I want that.  How would I go about doing that?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the "umbrella frameworks" (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkBinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002256-BAJICBDD)?
Not sure it is possible to create a custom umbrella framework for iphone.
BTW, static library != framework

Comment: Yeah pretty much.  I want to be able to only need to link to (HighLevelLibrary) to create a working project.  Is this even possible with static libraries?  Funny enough, I'm moving all of this stuff into static libraries from Mac frameworks.  The Mac frameworks were very easy to set up and work great.  However, the process of moving this stuff to iPhone has been awful.  You'd think this kind of thing would be relatively easy, but it really hasn't been...

Comment: After a stunning amount of work I have resolved the issue: gather all of the files I wanted to use in separate libraries and make one big-ass library for all of them.  Not very elegant, but it works.  Thanks for the input, folks!